# Why do I get an "Type 'IPoint' is not defined" error in VB.NET

Tags: arcmap, vb.net, add-in, visual-studio

I am writing an add-in for ArcMap 10. I am trying to do Dim clickedPoint as IPoint in VB.NET, but I get "Type 'IPoint' is not defined" error. Do I have to import a class or how do I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since you are presumably using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) (not [VB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_basic), which is 20+ years old and no longer supported), you need to use the [`Imports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) statement to import [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29).

Specifically you want to put `Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry` at the top of your code files.

Alternatively you could fully qualify the IPoint type every time you use it (`ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint`) but that gets old quick.

**Tip:** In Visual Studio, use the context-sensitive chip that appears when you hover over a type name with a missing namespace declaration, and click the first option to automatically add an Imports statement for the discovered namespace. This will only work as long as you have a reference to the type's assembly in your project and there is no ambiguity as to its namespace.

Comment: I tried all this, but it doesn't work. When I use the import statement it seems as though it can't find the Geometry class. I get a warning "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry' doesn't contain any public  member or cannot be found. etc etc etc"

Comment: You need to add a reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry. In Solution Explorer -> Right Click on References -> Add Reference -> Select ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry

Comment: Instead of using "Add Reference", you should use "Add ArcGIS Reference", since that automatically sets the Specific Version to False.